# Python ftplib - specify port

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I would like to specify the port with Python's ftplib client (instead of default port 21).

Here is the code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('localhost') # connect to host, default port
```

Is there an easy way to specify an alternative port?

Answer (score 26):

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> HOST = "localhost"
>>> PORT = 12345 # Set your desired port number
>>> ftp = FTP()
>>> ftp.connect(HOST, PORT)
```

Answer (score 13):

After searching numerous solutions, a combination of the [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) and the `connect` command solved my issue.

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

host = 'host'
port = 12345
usr = 'user'
pwd = 'password'
ftps = FTP_TLS()
ftps.connect(host, port)
# Output: '220 Server ready for new user.'
ftps.login(usr, pwd)
# Output: '230 User usr logged in.'
ftps.prot_p()
# Output: '200 PROT command successful.'
ftp.nlst()
# Output: ['mysubdirectory', 'mydoc']
```

If you're using plain FTP instead of FTPS, just use `ftplib.FTP` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use [connect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.connect)

```
from ftplib import FTP

my_ftp = FTP()
my_ftp.connect('localhost', 80) # 80 is the port for example
```

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer. Instantiate the FTP object and then run connect on it like so:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect('localhost', 2121)
```

Comment: 8 years later and Doco still not reflecting this usage.