# Python ftplib: socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, sockets, ftp, ftplib

I need to create simple code that will upload a .csv file to an FTP server. The code is below.

```
import ftplib
import os
import sys
sourceFilePath = '/home/user/dir/'
filename = 'testing.csv'
destinationDirectory = 'anotherDirectory'
server = 'ftp://12.123.12.234'
username = 'aUser'
password = 'passwd1234'
myFTP = ftplib.FTP(server, username, password)
myFTP.cwd('/anotherDirectory/')
myFTP.storbinary('STOR '+filename, open(filename,'rb'))
myFTP.quit()
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./UploadToFTP.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "./UploadToFTP.py", line 13, in uploadFileFTP
    myFTP = ftplib.FTP(server, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 134, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), 
self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Has anyone seen this before? It seems rather generic to me and doesn't tell me much. So far as other code I've seen performing this same task, I don't have any currently visible errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no *"Undetermined error"* anywhere in your message.

Comment: It's indeterminable by me. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `host` argument of `ftplib.FTP` constructor is a hostname/IP address, not a URL.

So this is wrong:

```
server = 'ftp://12.123.12.234'
```

It should be:

```
server = '12.123.12.234'
```

---

If your URL contains a custom port, see [Python ftplib - specify port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17204276/850848).