# Python ftplib - Errno 10061- No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I want to establish a FTP connection to Windows server (let's say 10.20.30.50)
I am using Python **ftblib** package

```
session = ftplib.FTP('10.20.30.40','admin','password@123')
file = open('download.jpg','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR download.jpg', file)     # send the file
file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

But I am getting the error

> socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I tried `telnet 10.20.30.40 8081` and it is successful.

I allow port 8081 for ftp. I open port by adding new inbound rules.

I tried several available solutions on Stack Overflow as well as other sites but they all are talking about to check the port. I do all the things but still no help.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly did you *"try telnet"*? Did you connect to port 21 using telnet? From the same machine that runs your Python code? + *"I opened specific port also for connection"* - That's pretty vague. Where/how did you *"opened port"*?

Comment: Did you copy your first code line correctly? It has an odd number of apostrophes so it doesn't parse the way it should. I don't think *that* is the cause of your bug, but if you didn't copy the code correctly there's a risk we're not seeing what your actual problem is.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am using telent by this way-- telnet 10.20.30.40 8081. I allow port 8081 for ftp. I open port by adding new inbound rules

Comment: @alkanen I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

If your FTP server uses a non-standard port (8081), you have to specify that, when using `FTP` class.

```
session = ftplib.FTP()
session.connect('10.20.30.40', 8081)
session.login('admin','password@123')
```

See also [Python ftplib - specify port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17204276/850848).

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to enable FTP service in server. I followed this link and it is solved my issue

https://medium.com/@JohGeoCoder/allowing-ftp-access-on-windows-server-2016-hosted-on-microsoft-azure-af25898df958